# Is it safe to call kclass.memberProperties on an unknown (Any) object?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I assumed that it's OK to just access `members` field of a `KClass` object. But I have found a case when it's not. Both tests throw exceptions.

```
@Test fun mapProperties() {
    val map = mapOf("a" to "b")
    val cls = map.javaClass.kotlin
    cls.members
}
```

Throws: `kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Incorrect resolution sequence for Java field public open val values: kotlin.collections.MutableCollection<(V..V?)> defined in java.util.Collections.SingletonMap[JavaPropertyDescriptor@10163d6]`

```
@Test fun mapProperties2() {
    val map = mapOf("a" to "b")
    val cls = clsByReified(map)
    cls.members
}

inline fun <reified T: Any> clsByReified(instance: T): KClass<T> {
    return T::class
}
```

Throws: `kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError: No metadata found for public abstract val entries: [Not-computed] defined in kotlin.collections.Map[DeserializedPropertyDescriptor@5c1a8622]`

Not sure if I stumbled upon a bug or just missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed recently and is available in nightly builds. The upcoming Kotlin 1.0.2 release will include the fix. Here's the original issue: [KT-11258](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11258).